# Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingProvider[48] An error occurred while reading the key ring

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core-2.1, asp.net-core-identity, key-management

This issue only comes when i deploy the ASP .NET Core 2.1 Web App on shared hosting. I am using Azure Key vault with PersistKeysToFileSystem.

Web App is working good on my development machine and on Azure App with and without Azure Key Vault using PersistKeysToFileSystem.

``` fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingProvider[48]
      An error occurred while reading the key ring.
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask``1.get_Result()
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask``1.get_Result()
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.WaitForCreatedConnectionAsync(ValueTask``1 creationTask)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask``1.get_Result()
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncBuffered(Task``1 sendTask, HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts)
   at Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.KeyVaultCredential.ProcessHttpRequestAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.KeyVaultClient.WrapKeyWithHttpMessagesAsync(String vaultBaseUrl, String keyName, String keyVersion, String algorithm, Byte[] value, Dictionary``2 customHeaders, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.KeyVaultClientExtensions.WrapKeyAsync(IKeyVaultClient operations, String keyIdentifier, String algorithm, Byte[] key, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.AzureKeyVault.AzureKeyVaultXmlEncryptor.EncryptAsync(XElement plaintextElement)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.AzureKeyVault.AzureKeyVaultXmlEncryptor.Encrypt(XElement plaintextElement)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.XmlEncryption.XmlEncryptionExtensions.EncryptIfNecessary(IXmlEncryptor encryptor, XElement element)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager.Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.Internal.IInternalXmlKeyManager.CreateNewKey(Guid keyId, DateTimeOffset creationDate, DateTimeOffset activationDate, DateTimeOffset expirationDate)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager.CreateNewKey(DateTimeOffset activationDate, DateTimeOffset expirationDate)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingProvider.CreateCacheableKeyRingCore(DateTimeOffset now, IKey keyJustAdded)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingProvider.Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.Internal.ICacheableKeyRingProvider.GetCacheableKeyRing(DateTimeOffset now)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingProvider.GetCurrentKeyRingCore(DateTime utcNow)
Hosting environment: Production ```

Comment: I am expecting the same problem. Are you using `AddAzureKeyVault` ?

Comment: I faced this issue along with some others only on IONOS windows hosting due to a lot of errors in their custom hosting panel. After changing my hosting provider issue was resolved.

Answer (score 5):

I faced this issue after installing Active Directory, and my solution is set "Load User Profile" to "True" for the IIS Application Pool.

Comment: This didn't work for me. Anyone else have any other ideas?